# How to have subtabs with jQueryUI?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, user-interface, tabs

We have an interface standard in our application of tabs vertically down the left hand side. 95% of the time this is all we need and everything is fine.

```
| Tab          | Content
| Selected Tab
| Tab          |
```

What we have now is a tab that needs to be broken into sub sections. We dont really wish to swap to horizontal tabs across the top for the subcontent sections. What would be ideal is if one of the side tabs could expand down to show selectable children tabs.

```
| Tab          | Content of Selected Tab Child 2
| Selected Tab |
 |   Child 1   |
 |   Child 2
 |   Child 3   |
| Tab          |
```

Is there a plugin for jQueryUI that already does something like this? Or are we starting from scratch?

Comment: can you set up a demo of your current "horizontal" solution?

Comment: er, we dont have a current horizontal solution?

Answer (score 1):

[jquery-vert-tabs](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-vert-tabs/) has support for nested tabs, but AFAIK not the clean way you wanted...

[image: screenshot of jquery-vert-tabs example of nested tabs]

What are you currently using for vertical tabs? jQuery UI does not support it, so I'm assuming you're either using another plugin, or have a custom made solution.

If you don't find a better way, I'd suggest creating a menu with "regular" tabs and "sub" tabs, the latter with some indentation (using `padding-left` or adding some `&nbsp;` before it) and hidden by default. When you click in a regular tab, all sub tabs would be hidden, except for the sub tabs of the clicked one, which would be displayed. Depending on what you're currently using, that shouldn't be too hard to implement...